# Add SQLite dtabase file from a class library to ASP.NET Core MVC output directory on project build

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-package

I created a class library project and put my SQLite database in it, and set these lines in the `.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Data\DataBase\locations.db">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

If I locally reference that class library to my main project (ASP.NET Core), it works fine and on every build it will copy the database file to this directory:

```
***\bin\Debug\net5.0\Data\DataBase
```

But when I publish the class library to NuGet, and install it in my main project, it doesn't copy the file.

Any help why this is happening and what should I do?

This is my package in NuGet package explorer

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just find out the answer

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Data\DataBase\locations.db">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

This line will do the job

```
<PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
```